# Copy data from a SQL Server table into a historic table and add a timestamp of the time copied?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to work out a specific way to copy all data from a particular table (let's call it `opportunities`) and copy it into a new table, with a timestamp of the date copied into the new table, for the sole purpose of generating historic data into a database hosted in `Azure Data Warehousing`.

What's the best way to do this? So far I've gone and created a duplicate table in the data warehouse, with an additional column called `datecopied`

The query I've started using is:

```
SELECT OppName, Oppvalue
INTO Hst_Opportunities
FROM dbo.opportunities
```

I am not really sure where to go from here!

Comment: You're attempting to partition your data. Searching with that term should help. What version of SQL Server is this? If it's 2016 partitioning is available at the standard level in SP1.

Comment: Thanks - its 2005 but im syncing the data to a Azure data warehouse using Azure Data Factory. Based on the comments below though i may change this to be a Azure SQL 2016 Server IAAS server.

Comment: just did a bit of reading - will horizontal partitioning allow me to generate a graph through powerbi showing growth of potential revenue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT INTO` is not supported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse at this time.  You should familiarise yourself with the [CREATE TABLE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas) or [CTAS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204041.aspx) syntax, which is the equivalent in Azure DW.

If you want to fix the copy date, simply assign it to a variable prior to the `CTAS`, something like this:

```
DECLARE @copyDate DATETIME2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

CREATE TABLE dbo.Hst_Opportunities
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
)
AS 
SELECT OppName, Oppvalue, @copyDate AS copyDate
FROM dbo.opportunities;
```

I should also mention that the use case for Azure DW is million and billions of rows with terabytes of data.  It doesn't tend to do well at low volume, so consider if you need this product, a traditional SQL Server 2016 install, or Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Ok thanks, thats really good food for thought. the database size itself is about 5GB of CRM data, so it probably doesnt justify a data warehouse then for historic data.

Comment: continued comment: ultimately what i'm after is to be able to graph the total sum of potential revenue in the business on a monthly basis, at the time of that month to show a growth or decline in potential revenue.

Comment: Hi wBob, jut to follow up from this suggestion, i've attempted to add to the "from" field the database name that exists on another server. essentially what im trying to do is run a select query from a table in one server and copy the results with a timestamp to the warehouse - im wondering if i should just be using regular SQL instead?

Comment: Based on your volumes, I would say Azure SQL Database (not Warehouse) or normal SQL Server would probably be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You can write insert into select query like below which will work with SQL Server 2008 +, Azure SQL datawarehouse

```
INSERT INTO Hst_Opportunities 
   SELECT OppName, Oppvalue, DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'},current_timestamp) 
   FROM dbo.opportunities
```

Comment: Wouldn't this lead for big dumps to changing milliseconds, secods, minutes? Just in case later on one wants to select a specific dump.

Comment: I thought you would be using datettime for date copied.
For specific dump you can retrieve unix_timestamp using 
DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, current_timestamp)
this will return unix_timestamp in seconds value.

I just updated my answer as well.

Comment: it will not as it is restricted to seconds part

Comment: We have jobs which run for minutes and create one timestamp beforehand, using this for all incoming data.

Comment: i am not getting your actual issue, if you can ellaborate then it will be easy to reolve the issue.